# Lock Entire Row Based On Date

Tags: vba, excel

I have Cell A1 with Month mentioned. I am trying to compare date in A2:last cell and wherever date > A1, I want the row to be unlocked, otherwise locked. The below code doesn't work"

```
Sub Lockrow()
Dim DestSh As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Integer

Set DestSh = Sheets("Consultant & Volunteer")

With DestSh
    'finds the last row with data on A column
    lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  'parse all rows
    For i = 6 To lastrow
       'if your conditions are met
       If Month(.Cells(i, 26)) > Month(.Cells(1, 1)) Then
          .Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Cells.Locked = True 'lock the row
       End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Your `For` loop through cells in Column "Z" (`.Cells(i, 26)`), and if you have only 1 Cell with data in Column A (Cell A1), then you might exit the loop without going in even once inside to check for the `If` condition (since lastrow could be = 1)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done simply with below, but you have to be careful that Year doesn't change... Also the `lastrow` should be on Column Z.

Also, if the worksheet isn't Protected, there is no effect.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Lockrow()
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Long ' Integer

    Set DestSh = Sheets("Consultant & Volunteer")

    With DestSh
        'finds the last row with data on A column
        lastrow = .Range("Z" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' <-- EDIT
        'parse all rows
        For i = 6 To lastrow
           'if your conditions are met               
           .Rows(i).Locked = Not (Month(.Cells(i, "Z")) > Month(.Range("A1")))
'           If Month(.Cells(i, 26)) > Month(.Cells(1, 1)) Then
'              .Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Cells.Locked = True 'lock the row
'           End If
        Next i
        .Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    End With
    Set DestSh = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. It's giving me error at - 
.Rows(i).Locked = Not (Month(.Cells(i, "Z")) > Month(.Range("A1")))

and if I change A1 to a full date instead of month, the code works however doesnt lock anything.

Comment: I guess there isn't data on column A below row 6? I have changed to use column Z instead of A for the `lastrow`.

Comment: Doesn't work still. A1 to A8 I have data filled in, and Z1 to Z8 as well. Template headers end at row 5 hence I started the loop from row 6.

Comment: Awesome! adding the userinterfaceonly code makes it work now! 
However, quick question.. It is also locking all blank rows in the sheet as well. This won't allow user to add new data.. Can we make all empty rows unlocked?

Comment: @ManpreetGujral Unlock all of the cells first then run this code

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀 I tried. It's locking the empty cells too. The ones below lastrow.

Comment: @ManpreetGujral All cells by default are protected, so you have to select all the cells then right click and uncheck the Locked in the Protection menu

Comment: @ManpreetGujral: FWIW, put this line: `.Cells.Locked = False` between `With DestSh` and `lastrow = .Range("Z" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` to unlock the cells automatically.

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀 What could I do to unlock column Z onwards? Instead of locking entire row can I specify that only lock column until Z?

Comment: @ManpreetGujral Maybe put this line: `.Columns("AA:XFD").Locked = False` before `.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True`. Not sure this way would work for your need.

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀 It worked!!!! Thank you! 
One last question, I wrote this code to match month as well as year in A1 (instead of just month).. but it doesnt work, it only matches Month. 
  .Rows(i).Locked = Not (Month(.Cells(i, "Z")) & Year(.Cells(i, "Z")) >= (Month(.Range("A1")) & Year(.Range("A1"))))

Comment: @ManpreetGujral If the data in the specific cells is in date types, why not use `.Rows(i).Locked = Not (.Cells(i, "Z") >= .Range("A1"))`?

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀 Basically I am unlocking only rows for the entire month specified in A1, hence cant compare full dates. 
For ex - If A1 is October 2016, column Z is date of joining of an employee.. so whoever joined before October 2016 need to be locked, rest needs to be open for editing.

Comment: @ManpreetGujral It still works I guess since Excel interprets Oct 2016 as Sep 30, 2016 11:59:59 p.m (the end of the day).

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to loop.

```
Dim r As Range, DestSh As Worksheet, lastrow As Long
Set DestSh = Sheets("Consultant & Volunteer")
With DestSh
    lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set r = .Range("A1:A" & lastrow)
    r.EntireRow.Locked = False
    r.AutoFilter 1, ">" & .Range("A1").Value2
    r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Locked = True
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
End With
```

Comment: This code filters column A, however my date to run the loop on is in column Z.

Comment: @ManpreetGujral Then adjust the code to suit. Typing Z in place of A isn't so hard :)